# How do I track where a conversion 'came from'?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads, linkedin

I want to advertise on Google Adwords AND Linked-In. However I want to know which is more successful at getting a conversion.

I'm not really sure how to set things up so that I can do this? I have installed Google Analytics. And I have a campaign running but yeah no idea really. Do I just set up a goal and then GA will tell me where the referral came from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, first you need to define a conversion. Easiest way to do it without custom programming is to define URL Conversions. For this, you must have unique URLs which only happen when conversion is made (e.g. a special URL on a thank-you page which is shown only after conversion is made).

When you have conversions setup, there are reports which allow you to see the referrals for conversions.